# how to install gvfs-mtp backend in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, apt, nautilus, ppa, gvfs

as given on the launchpad page [here](https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp)

> **PPA description**
>
> ---
>
> These builds of gvfs have my native mtp backend backported from gvfs master. Use this to easily access MTP based devices with Nautilus.
>   13.10 (Saucy) and newer versions of Ubuntu contain all of these changes, so you don't need to use this ppa any more.

i'm using ubuntu 12.10 ,so I decided to install this package.

so i first added the repository.

> aditya@aditya-desktop:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp

and then

> sudo apt-get update

**But i don't know what and how to install to get that package**

please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It updates the existing `gvfs-backends` package with the newer one, which contains the GVFS-MTP backend. Just let the package manager install the updated packages and you're good.

Comment: actually i got it somehow.